# Which gym is ideal? A gym with warm temperature or a cooler one

Tags: weight-loss, gym, calories

It's been about more than a month that I have been going to a gym to lose some weight and build some strength. In general, we have AC in a gym, but in my gym they don't have AC and no ceiling fan, only some table fans for occasional relief.

My brother went with me to that gym and advocated that it is a good gym — not like the fancy ones with air conditioning — and that here you will lose more weight.

I interrupted him, saying that calorie burn depends on workouts and not on the outside temperature, but my brother said I know nothing.

**So I want to ask whether the temperature in the gym matters regarding the amount of calories burned. I am talking about some significant difference.**

Comment: It can make a big difference. The more you sweat your body tends to release more bad toxins and water weight. The overall difference isn't great but it definitely helps make you feel like you've had a better workout also

Comment: @Twyxz do you have studies backing up the toxin release statement? Our liver and kidneys deal with pretty much all of the toxins in the body.

Comment: Relevant- https://youtu.be/P5GFbW042c0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tiny picture**

A common misconception is that sweating more means a more intense workout. This is false. Sweating simply means the body wants to cool down. Otherwise people could get completely ripped sitting in a sauna.

I've heard claims that sweating more lowers weight, which is true. It's just water and salt. It all comes back in the next meal.

Working out in a gym might make a *slight* difference in caloric burn because the extra energy it takes to produce more sweat. On the flip side, working out in a freezing gym might make a *slight* difference because of the extra shivering. If all things are equal, working out in a warm gym would hold the advantage.

**Big picture**

The single deciding factor of success in the gym will be whether you perform to your fullest ability each workout, and being consistent. Doing half the work because you're uncomfortable will result in less progress regardless of the gym temperature. Skipping the scheduled workout because it's too unpleasant will halt progress.

Some people can workout in super-hot gyms, and may even prefer it. That's great as long as they are practicing [progressive overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_overload) and not lowering volume to compensate the added stress. Some people may work better either physically or mentally in a more moderate temperature. That's fine as well as long as they are practicing progressive overload.  The people who stay consistent are the people who progress.